# Ajax Datatable's Export Button only exporting visible data

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, datatables-1.10

I am using ajax datatable for showing data. I am having issue with the export button. What by default is happening is on click of button it is only exporting visible data but what i actually want is it should be exporting all the data (if filtered then that too).
Tried various export options as

```
dom: 'lfBrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]

            }
        },
                    {
            extend: 'csv',
           exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
                search: 'applied',
                order: 'applied',
                page: 'all'
            }
        }
            },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                search: 'applied',
                order: 'applied',
                page: 'all'
            }
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
```

But none of them seems to be working. Any help ??

Comment: Try by Removing  ':visible'

Comment: Not working, even removed copy field still csv or excel exporting visible data

Comment: That also doesn't worked. I want to export all the data on export not just the one which is visible (because of pagination). Just used page: 'all' but that also didn't worked

Comment: What I found there is export buttons are at client end and I'm fetching data from server side. Tried various possibilities mentioned there  (other people's query ) but none seems to be working

Comment: @Nikhil, if you are using ajax and fetching data at server side, then how can you expect to export all data at client side?, because when you call pagination number, in browser network call, you can see that it is fetching next few data.